# Play several sound effects simultaneously using OpenSL ES Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, opensl

I'm using OpenSL ES for playing music and sounds in my project. I've used *native-audio sample* as start and it's fine for reproduce background music and a single sound but when I try to reproduce two or more sounds at same time the sounds aren't reproduced simultaneously because the sound buffers are enqueued for playback when all previous buffers are played.

Then, after a little research, **I've found two ways to fix it**, in short:

> 1. Use several audio players (and therefore buffer queues) for reproduce the sounds.
> 2. Mix the sound effects buffers together into a single buffer and then enqueue.

My questions are: 
**What do you think is the best approach? There's a better way that I've ignored?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with OpenSL ES as well. Little bit complicated ay the beginning...

Anyway you can create as much ObjectPlayer you want, always remember that the maximum ammount of objects is 32.

So, ideally, if you want to play 4 sounds at the same time, you need 4 PlayerObject and 1 OutputMixObject

Hope you can find usefull

Answer (score 0):

Here's a completely different approach: I'm using [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) to do this: It's very simple and it works perfectly.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. I used SoundPool in an old project and, yes, it's very simple, even working with c++ is easy to implement, but for me SoundPool had two big problems, **it crashed on Galaxy S devices** and it was very **unstable** ( Some sounds never played, first play didn't work... ).